# oracle - order by in subselect

Tags: oracle, subquery, sql-order-by

i'm trying to execute the following sql statement on oracle:

```
SELECT
  a.*, b.*
FROM
    v$sql a, 
    v$sql_bind_capture b
WHERE
  b.sql_id = a.sql_id 
  AND 
    b.sql_id IN 
     ( select sql_id from v$sql where rownm < 100 order by elapsed_time desc)
ORDER BY
  b.child_address, b.position
```

Error code is "missing right parenthesis.

I would like to get the 100 top statements from v$sql ordered by elapsed_time and then afterwarts getting the corresponding-binds from view v$sql_bind_capture.

Can somebody help me, thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM v$sql a, v$sql_bind_capture b 
WHERE b.sql_id = a.sql_id 
AND b.sql_id IN ( SELECT * from 
(select sql_id from v$sql order by elapsed_time desc) 
WHERE rownum <=100 ) 
ORDER BY b.child_address, b.position
```

Some more info [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/top_records.php).

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment, the first thing that struck me, is this is 99 not 100.

Comment: Ups my fault. I've changed `<100` to `<=100`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM V$SQL ORDER BY ELAPSED_TIME DESC ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 100 ) a
       INNER JOIN
       v$sql_bind_capture b
       ON ( b.sql_id = a.sql_id )
ORDER BY
       b.child_address,
       b.position;
```